# iOS AdHoc app works perfectly in simulator, refuses to launch on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The app, which is for personal use, has worked perfectly for one year on my device.

Suddenly it stopped working. It would show the startup image briefly, and then quit immediately. That didn't surprise me, because the same thing happened with my other app, as my provisioning profile was expired. On the other app, I fixed it by rebuilding the app in Xcode, and it worked again. On the app that doesn't work, I can build it with Xcode and run in the simulator only, but if I try to run it on the device, either via Xcode or by archiving and exporting, the same thing happens: Launch image shown briefly, then it quits immediately. Xcode gives this error message:

```
Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AD405D63-426C-401B-8678-726D60BCB6F8/QuickDict.app
```

I have not been able to find any more diagnostics information. I notice that for my other app, the one that worked, Xcode uses a provisioning profile with a full app identifier, as in "com.domain.AppName", whereas for the app that doesn't work, it uses a profile with a wildcard app identifier. However, I need no capabilities for this one app that I know of. I let Xcode handle signing automatically.

On the device, the app won't run neither when launching via Xcode nor when trying to install the app via iTunes.

- Xcode version: 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
- Deployment target: iPhone iOS 9.2
- Device: iPhone 5s

It is not guaranteed that the reason has to do with provisioning profiles, because some code has been changed after it was last deployed. However, it works perfectly in the simulator.

---

EDIT: I saw that my app was set up to run with release build in Xcode. I tried running the debug build instead, and got a new equally "informative" error message:

```
Could not launch "QuickDict"
process launch failed: Unspecified
```

---

EDIT2: In this case I had a different domain name available, and was able to get the app to work simply by changing the (domain name in the) app identifier. Clearly Xcode had an expired provisioning profile in the system which it insisted on using. This is not an ideal solution for others, so I will not write it as an answer, although the problem now no longer exists for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen adhoc based provisioning profile ,you have to choose development based provisioning profile .
Go to [developer.apple](http://Developer.apple) and download your app development provisioning profile then choose in Xcode build setting -> code signing tab then launch I am sure you will able to launch your app as well.

Thanks.